# Is it possible to perform a case-sensitive search in OpenGrok?

Tags: opengrok

Looking at the OpenGrok help page reveals that the search query is based on Lucene, and Lucene in turn indicates that search queries are converted to lower case. I was wondering if there is any way to change this behavior and perform a case-sensitive search.

Comment: Which version you are using.Use the latest one , I am using opengrok-0.12-rc2 and its working fine .

Answer (score 3):

Reference search (-r) is case sensitive, as is definition (-d).

Comment: That may be, but I want to do a full search with case matching.